# Classe não atualiza valor no JS

Tags: javascript, classes

gente estou fazendo um exercício para criar um sistema de banco onde tem saldo e deposito nas contas corrente e poupança. Porém , quando tento adicionar um valor à classe para somar valores as contas ou saber o saldo o valor que está no prompt não entra na classe.

```
class Saldo {
constructor(contaCorrente,contaPoupanca,jurosPoupanca){
    this.contaCorrente = contaCorrente;
    this.contaPoupanca = contaPoupanca;
    this.jurosPoupanca = jurosPoupanca;  
};

deposito(contaCorrente,contaPoupanca){

 
 let escolha = prompt('o deposito sera no conta corrente : 1 ou na conta poupanca : 2 ? ');
 if (escolha == 1){
    escolha = contaCorrente;
     var contaC = prompt('qual valor vc deseja depositar na conta corrente ?');
    console.log('voce depositou na conta corrente: ' + contaC + ' reais.');
  
   
 } if (escolha == 2){
    escolha = contaPoupanca;
    contaPoupanca = this.contaPoupanca;
    var contaP = prompt('qual valor vc deseja depositar na conta poupanca ?');
    console.log('voce depositou na conta poupanca: ' + contaP + ' reais.');
    contaP += this.contaPoupanca;
 } ;

  escolha !== 2 ||escolha!==1 

  contaCorrente += this.contaCorrente;
    
};

     saldo(contaC,contaP){
     let escolha = prompt('qual conta deseja acessar o saldo conta corrente : 1 ou conta poupança : 2 , ?');

        if(escolha == 1 ){
            contaC = this.contaCorrente;
            console.log('o seu saldo na conta corrente é de : ' + contaC);
        } else if (escolha == 2 ){
            contaP = this.contaPoupanca;
            console.log('o seu saldo na conta poupanca é de : ' + contaP);
        };

        contaC += this.contaCorrente;

};


set setSaldoCorrente (setSaldo){
   let  value = setSaldo +  this.contaCorrente;
    console.log('o seu saldo na conta corrente é de : ' + value)
};


set setSaldoPoupanca (setSaldo){
    setSaldo = this.contaPoupanca;
    console.log('o seu saldo na conta poupanca é de : ' + setSaldo)
};
```

}

let luiza = new Saldo( 0,0,0,0);
luiza.deposito();
luiza.saldo();
console.log(luiza);

Comment: construtor de `Saldo` é 3 parâmetros mas passou 4. a função `deposito` e `saldo` esta usando variáveis locais... algumas partes do código não faz o que deveria fazer.

Comment: Vc poderia dar um exemplo de quais partes exatamente nn estão funcionando e como ajustar essa situação do deposito e saldo ?

Comment: @stack.cardoso mt obg mesmo comecei a programar por agr e nossa me ajudou mt mesmo , obg tbm pela toda explicação no código <3